# Showing that changing scalars do not change the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. I want to prove that $k \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} V$ still has dimension $n$ as a vector space over $k$. Any explanation/comments/answers are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Choose a basis, and prove it remains a basis over $k$

Comment: What do I do if I have a vector space where it is a $\mathbb{Q}$-span of $\{ [1,1], [i,i] \}$ or something?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question, but I think it just doesn't matter: an $n$ dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$ is isomorphic to the space of $n$-tuples $\Bbb Q^n$ (by coordinating in a basis).

Comment: @JohnnyT. Look again the definition of $\otimes_\mathbb{Q}$. If $V = \mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathbb{Q}(i) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} V$ has dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ because the $i$ of $V$ and the $i$ of $\mathbb{Q}(i) $ are not the same. To make them the same you need to look at $\mathbb{Q}(i) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}(i)} V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_1,\dots, e_n$ be a basis of $V$ over $\Bbb Q$ so that any $v\in V$ can be uniquely coordinated as
$$v\ =\ \lambda_1e_1+\dots+\lambda_ne_n$$
with $\lambda_i\in\Bbb Q$.

Any elements $u$ of $k\otimes_{\Bbb Q} V$ is of the form $\sum_ja_j\otimes v_j$ with $a_j\in k$. Coordinating each $v_j$ in $e_1,\dots, e_n$ will lead to
$$u\ =\ b_1\otimes e_1+\dots+ b_n\otimes e_n$$
with $b_i\in k$, so $1\otimes e_1,\dots, 2\otimes e_n$ is a generating system of the $k$-vector space. 
That they are also linearly independent, follows by the properties of tensor product.

Comment: I think I got it now... thank you!